# Delete subdocuments which meet a criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In my collection I've got two arrays with subdocuments. I would like to delete all subdocuments inside of these arrays which meet a certain criteria. This is how my document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5935a41f12f3fac949a5f925"),
    "project_id" : 13,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-07-04T13:10:11.006Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-06-05T18:34:07.150Z"),
    "uploaded_files" : [ 
        {
            "display_name" : "CoC_Bot.Main.locale (1).pot",
            "file" : ObjectId("595b93b298b07d206c0d6153"),
            "upload_id" : ObjectId("595b93ac98b07d206c0d6152"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-04T13:10:11.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "file_history" : [ 
        {
            "display_name" : "Log_28-6-2017_14-17-53-562 (1).txt",
            "file" : ObjectId("595b93ac98b07d206c0d6151"),
            "upload_id" : ObjectId("595b93ac98b07d206c0d6152"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-04T13:10:04.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "display_name" : "CoC_Bot.Main.locale (1).pot",
            "file" : ObjectId("595b93b298b07d206c0d6153"),
            "upload_id" : ObjectId("595b93ac98b07d206c0d6152"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-04T13:10:11.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to delete all subdocuments from `uploaded_files` and `file_history` which match the upload_id x. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just via mongoose or it could be mongo shell too?

Comment: Mongoose is what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you can use $pull**

```
COLLECTION.update(
    {project_id:12}, /* condition */ 
    {$pull: {file_history:{upload_id: ID}}}, 
    {multi:true, new: true})
    .exec(function(err, docs){

    });
```